# How to save generated output text files in an user selected-folder, in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a VBA code where I generate text files. I am passing 7 arguments into a sub-method to generate all text files. However, I am having difficulties to save the generated files into a user-selected folder. When I run the code, it just saves all the files to the included path (for now since I don't know how to do what I explain above).

Below is my code where I am trying to incorporate the path that I can use to let any user select a folder to save all the generated text files.

```
Sub TextFiles()

Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject, Path As String

'Ask user to save files into a folder
Path = "C:\Users\samplename\Desktop\TEST"


'Call sub procedure to generate text files and store them in NewFolderPath
CreateTxtFiles.CreateTxtFiles Path & "\sample1.txt", 1, "sample1", "sample1_", 7, "sample1_2", 9
CreateTxtFiles.CreateTxtFiles Path & "\sample2.txt", 2, "sample2", "sample2_", 9, "0", 0
CreateTxtFiles.CreateTxtFiles Path & "\sample3.txt", 3, "sample3", "sample3", 5, "0", 0
CreateTxtFiles.CreateTxtFiles Path & "\sample4.txt", 4, "sample4", "sample4", 5, "0", 0
```

End Sub

Comment: "*I am having difficulties...*" What difficulties? What happens when you try it? Do you get an error? Does it go to the wrong folder? Please be specific so we can help you.

Comment: @freginold, please see edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ShellFolderPicker As Object
    Dim FolderPath As String

    Set ShellFolderPicker = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    FolderPath = ShellFolderPicker.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder to Save Files:", 0).Self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

    CreateTxtFiles.CreateTxtFiles FolderPath & "\sample1.txt", 1, "sample1", "sample1_", 7, "sample1_2", 9

End Sub
```

Comment: You rock! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `FileDialog.SelectedItems` Property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/filedialog-selecteditems-property-office

```
Sub TextFiles()

Dim MyFolder As FileDialog
Dim Path As Variant

Set MyFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With MyFolder
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        Path = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
    End If
End With


'Call sub procedure to generate text files and store them in NewFolderPath
CreateTxtFiles.CreateTxtFiles Path & "\sample1.txt", 1, "sample1", "sample1_", 7, "sample1_2", 9
CreateTxtFiles.CreateTxtFiles Path & "\sample2.txt", 2, "sample2", "sample2_", 9, "0", 0
CreateTxtFiles.CreateTxtFiles Path & "\sample3.txt", 3, "sample3", "sample3", 5, "0", 0
CreateTxtFiles.CreateTxtFiles Path & "\sample4.txt", 4, "sample4", "sample4", 5, "0", 0
```

Hope this helps!